# How can I generate a 100% random number between 1 and the max of a 32 bit int in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to generate a random number that populates an int in C#.

I have heard that sometimes random numbers are not reliable. Would this be a problem for me to generate a random number?

Can someone comment on this and suggest a very reliable way to generate a random number between 1 and the max of a 32 bit int?

Comment: If your requirement is only a single random number in such a big range, it will be 100% Random(not repeating). And Let me know what you meant by Reliable in this case? I think the question should be more clear and specific

Comment: What is the random number *for*? What do you mean by "reliable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
for(someloop) {
    int randomValue = random.Next(0, int.MaxValue) + 1;
}
```

Be aware that this is only pseudo random. This example is creating an instance of the random outside the loop, so it doesn't keep getting reseeded with the same current time. If you use random extensively, you could even make a singleton wrapper around it and use one instance of random for your entire application (be aware of threading issues of coarse).

Comment: "between 1 and ..."

Comment: Actually you would need to do `new Random().Next(0, int.MaxValue) + 1;` because `.Next` has a exclusive upper bound so the largest value you could get would be `int.MaxValue - 1`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you give me an example of how I could use this inside a loop. Is there a way to get the .Next value in the loop?